# magento2 input type number accept "E"

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

Hello I'm facing the issue, when I change the input type text to number then it will allow the small and capital E latter rest of all letter will not able to type from keyboard but how can we prevent this error using **js** in **magento2**

please check the images below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question explain this. It's because "e" can represent a floating number.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706611/why-does-the-html-input-with-type-number-allow-the-letter-e-to-be-entered-in/31706796

Answer (score 0):

The latter  "e" and "E" represent a floating number when you use the number as input type.

use below code to prevent it

```
<input type="number" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" />
```